# How to restore .BAK files ignoring table

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

I have this query.

```
USE [master];
DECLARE @Table TABLE (
    LogicalName varchar(128),
    [PhysicalName] varchar(128), 
    [Type] varchar, 
    [FileGroupName] varchar(128), 
    [Size] varchar(128),
    [MaxSize] varchar(128), 
    [FileId]varchar(128), 
    [CreateLSN]varchar(128), 
    [DropLSN]varchar(128), 
    [UniqueId]varchar(128), 
    [ReadOnlyLSN]varchar(128), 
    [ReadWriteLSN]varchar(128),
    [BackupSizeInBytes]varchar(128), 
    [SourceBlockSize]varchar(128), 
    [FileGroupId]varchar(128), 
    [LogGroupGUID]varchar(128), 
    [DifferentialBaseLSN]varchar(128), 
    [DifferentialBaseGUID]varchar(128), 
    [IsReadOnly]varchar(128), 
    [IsPresent]varchar(128), 
    [TDEThumbprint]varchar(128),
    [SnapshotUrl]varchar(128)
)
DECLARE @Path varchar(1000)='{1}/{0}.bak' 
DECLARE @LogicalNameData varchar(128),@LogicalNameLog varchar(128)
INSERT INTO @table
EXEC('
RESTORE FILELISTONLY
   FROM DISK=''' +@Path+ '''
   ')
   SET @LogicalNameData=(SELECT LogicalName FROM @Table WHERE Type='D')
   SET @LogicalNameLog=(SELECT LogicalName FROM @Table WHERE Type='L')

RESTORE DATABASE {0}
FROM DISK = '{1}/{0}.bak' 
WITH
        MOVE @LogicalNameData TO '{2}/{0}.mdf',
        MOVE @LogicalNameLog TO '{3}/{0}.ldf';
```

where {0},{1},{2} a local path I do replace.
But I need to ignore a specific table in the restore.

Example, my bak file exist: table1, table2, table3
I want to restore only table1, table2.. ignoring table3.
In my real case, I have 30 tables but I want to ignore just one.

Can any guy help-me?

Comment: "Can any guy help-me" - "Guy" frequently means male, I would highly recommend, in fact insist on, using gender neutral language e.g. "Can anyone help me".

Comment: You want to restore only some of the tables from a database backup?  That is not possible.  You can restore the backup to a new database and copy data between databases using SQL.

Comment: Please do not SHOUT when posting here (specifically the title of your question). Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read and understand, and SHOUTING won't get you help any faster. It's also pretty impolite to come here and SHOUT at us when you're asking us for free help.